# Kernel panic after updating Ubuntu (says syntax error)

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel

I am currently running 16.04. I then decided to update the applications and the system through:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After the successful upgrade, I decided to reboot the computer. It then showed the following message:

```
/init: conf/conf.d/resume: line 1: syntax error: unexpected "("
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted kill init! exitcode=0x00000200
CPU: 3 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu
Hardware name: LENOVO 20149/INVALID, BIOS 5ECN95WW(V9.00) 12/19/12
```

### What can I do to fix this?

[UPDATE]
Going to the recovery mode still results in a kernel panic. But, I managed to view the contents of `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` through Grub's command line interface.
The content of `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` is:
    RESUME=UUID=bb4423df-62ca-4f1f-9222-5e110e453fa6

Comment: Please see my comment, further below.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it's a corrupt init ramdisk image. I managed to solve something similar this way.

First boot into a recovery environment where you have access to a shell and necessary volumes of the original system (notably rootfs and /boot). Mount them and chroot into the original rootfs.

Delete all initramdisks:

```
update-initramfs -d -k all
```

Regenerate them:

```
update-initramfs -c -k all
```

Now reboot, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer... work in progress...

You may have a corrupt resume file, or a bad initramfs image.

To see if it's the resume file, do this:

1. Boot the computer and hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key right after the computer manufacturer's splash screen disappears.
2. Choose *Advanced options for Ubuntu*.
3. At the GNU GRUB menu choose *recovery mode*. Often (recovery mode) is the second entry from the top.
4. At the Recovery Menu, choose *root* access.
5. At the # prompt, type `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

Edit your question to include the output of the `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` command and we'll take a look.

I'll add more detail if I decide that it's a bad initramfs image.

Comment: @Gerald Are you able to boot into ANY recovery mode... like for your previous kernel, probably -71?